# Moving to another domain loss google search rank

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, transfer, site-move

My old A.maindomain.**net** was hosted on `wordpress.com` so I decided to move to B.maindomain.**com** domain and use Google Analytic and wordpress.org instead.

Actually, I have prepared test environment to make sure the redirect is working properly,

**So I did the following:**

- submitted the new domain with the site map to google webmaster. (the old one already added in webmaster).
- Exported from the old site and import it to the new wordpress.org with the same domain **A.**maindomain**.net**.
- Again, performed export and import from the old site to the new domain **B.**maindomain**.com**
- Applied the `redirect rule` and `RedirectMatch` to make sure the redirect worked properly
- last, I pointed the old domain to the new host and everything is working properly now.
- Finally, I applied to move to another site in google webmaster.

[image]

**On the first-day**, it was working properly from the search organic!

**Unfortunately, I am facing the following:**

- I lost all 1# Rank articles from the first google search page!!
- My old domain partially disappeared from search.
- Because of redirect, the old domain can't read the sitemap site "can't fetch". (**Is it normal?**)
  [image]
- The new domain crawled and indexed but not all pages!
- The number of visitors is less than the number before migration. it's about 60%

**Now I would like to know**

- What am I doing wrong?
- Am I lost my SEO ranking forever for these articles, I need to start from scratch or it will take some time to be replaced and go back to the 1st rank with the new domain.
- What's the effect of updating old 1st rank articles and indexed it manually?
- What's the effect of updating old articles in general to refresh the
  content and enhance SEO, Is it worth?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is very much normal. Google webmasters have lots of websites to track to. You need to give it time, Instead of using rewrite rule in .htaccess, Go to your domain control panel, and enter your redirects there. That way, Google won't loose traffic to your new domain.
Lastly. , Try deleting all the old sitemaps,. and add a new one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer

Comment: I am using .htaccess for a custom redirecting with 301 as well as I read the google support and they said adjust 301 Redirect in .htaccess! so domain redirect will not help in my case, so what do you think is it required to perform the redirect from domain too?

Comment: Also what about this point? **the old domain can't read the sitemap site "can't fetch"** and **updating old articles point**, thanks again for your help

Comment: Yes, of course. The domain forwarding or redirect in the domain control panel is a lot kore straight forward approach than the .htaccess. The . htaccess means, google visits your domain, then ur hosted space, then finds the redirect.

Comment: No, you have to regenerate your sitemap afresh. Try a sitemap generator or a plugin if your website is in a cms. Then re-up the sitemap to the google search console.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect the subdomain from the domain panel? I can find this option only for the main domain!

Comment: Regarding sitemap, are you talking about the old or new one, this issue for the old one because of redirect it can't access! but for the new it already has a fresh sitemap! please advice!

Comment: if your new sitemap has been indexed by the search console. then no need to worry. Your lost traffic will come back in some days.