# Could not featch site map error after perform redirect to a new domain

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

I have moved my site from one domain to another! and the migration and redirect have been done successfully!

Unfortunately, I lost the Google search rank for most of my pages!!

**Therefore,** I am trying to check anything that can help me to return back to the first page on google as before!

**In the old site,** I checked the webmaster and found out this error

> **"couldn't fetch"**.

[image]

**Is it normal? How to fix this issue?**

Now, I have decided to solve this error **"couldn't fetch"** by uploading the new sitemap with the new links to the old site. (**same URL articles with the new domain**)

I checked the webmaster sitemap status and it can read it now successfully **Is it correct?** I am afraid the submitted sitemap to the old site has the new site links!

> BTW, I have performed **move site action** from the old domain to the new domain from google webmaster and adjust redirect from .haccess file

Most of the experts said it's normal and the rank will come back soon! but it will take some time depends on a number of articles!

but actually, I only have about 400 URLs and still missing my top rank in google search after two weeks of moving!

More details at [Moving to another domain loss google search rank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127613/moving-to-another-domain-loss-google-search-rank)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't have anything to do with migration, Google is not being able to locate the Sitemap over your new domain.

As I commented [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127718/google-search-console-adding-sitemap-couldnt-fetch-and-sitemap-could-not-be/127726#127726), it may be a Google's bug, so try the following:

1. Use the Google Search Console Inspector Tool to make sure there is no robots.txt blocking your sitemap.
2. If the problem persists, try changing the sitemaps name. Use Sitemap2.xml and try again. You can also try changing the path: domain.com/sitemap/sitemap2.xml.

Comment: Thanks @em for your answer, but  The new sitemap can be fetched correctly at the new site in its webmaster, I am facing this issue for the old site and this issue happened after redirect! how can I solve it?

Comment: So, you had olddomain.com/sitemap.xml and now newdomain.com/sitemap.xml right? olddomain.com/sitemap.xml can't be fetched cause it has a redirect to newdomain.com/sitemap.xml. You should focus on the new site and forget about the old one cause the indexing URLs are from newdomain.com