# Why my site is not indexed

Tags: google-search

When I tried to search with `site:spgeeks.devoworx.com` I got only the below 4 results!

[image]

I am facing this issue 2 months ago and I can't trace my issue and there's no error in the search console! (*only excluded URLs (not post URL)*)
Could you please help me to know why my site is not indexed in google?

> **P.S:** I am not facing the same issue in bing and yahoo only in google!

Comment: How long ago did you move your website from `blog.devoworx.com` to `spgeeks.devoworx.com` and implement 301 redirects? Google can take a long time to crawl the new domain and update the results, especially if your site doesn't have many backlinks.

Comment: For future questions, it could be helpful to mention that the site was recently migrated across domains.

Comment: Thanks @MaximillianLaumeister for your guidelines, I moved my site 5 months ago, and this is the producers that I used to move https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127613/moving-to-another-domain-loss-google-search-rank Could you please help me on this!

Comment: I have many backlinks for my old domain, I am trying to update such links to the new domain!

Comment: Hopefully someone else will have some ideas. 5 months seems like a long time to me for a site to be in google limbo, especially while using the site move tool.

Comment: Thanks for your concern,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108688/discussion-between-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-and-maximillian-laumeister).