# Should I noindex or remove the old site after moving

Tags: google-search, site-move

I moved from `wordpress.com` that was mapped to a domain `A.net` to another domain `B.com` for 8 months ago.

Now the mapping between domain `A.net` and `wordpress.com` is expired but still domain `A.net` redirects (301) to domain `B.com`

So what Should I do,

- Remove `Wordpress.com` site permanently.
- Extend the wordpress.com mapping with domain A.net
- Discourage search engine to index Wordpress.com (I set this option for 1 month ago)
- Actually, I lost 100% rank from google, so if I rollbacked the move and remapped the `Wordpress.com` to domain `A.net` after enabling the discouragement of the search engine option, it will go back to its old rank!

Comment: Do you have 1 to 1 (url by url) mapping from wordpress to A.net to B.com?

Comment: There is a mapping like this melqassas@wordpress.com mapped to melqassas.net then I performed 301 redirects from melqassas.net to melqassas.com with different URL structure so, the map is between melqassas@wordpress.com mapped to melqassas.net and the redirect between  melqassas.net and melqassas.com

Comment: check, whether internal links from site B still contain site A, is the new sitemap correct with site B, is the search console correct - new property for site B created, active, error-free

Comment: What about wordpress.com, should I extend the mapping again or rollback the move? is it still has its rank in Google!

Comment: This is my case [link1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127613/moving-to-another-domain-loss-google-search-rank) and [link2](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/58639271?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mueller from Google recommends to keep redirects in place for **at least a year**:

> 301 is permanent, it means forever and that's a mighty long time, but I'm here to tell you, there's something else: the server maintenance.
> After a few years the old URLs are often no longer accessed & you can drop those redirects.
>
> https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1086228963721183232

> If they're no longer needed after a while (usually I recommend keeping them at least a year), and you don't see traffic to them, then removing them is fine since it makes long-term maintenance easier.
>
> https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1086241155728195584

Then, if you don't have an appreciable amount of users still accessing the old domain, you can let the domain and redirects lapse.

Do not discourage search engines from indexing domain A. This might cause them to stop indexing the redirects, which could harm the site move.